# conditional random field in semantic segmentation

Tags: deep-learning, crf, semantic-segmentation

Are CRF (Conditional Random Fields) still actively used in semantic segmentation tasks or do the current deep neural networks made them unnecessary ? 
I've seen both of the answers in academic papers and, since it seems quite complicated to implement and infer, I would like to have opinions on them before trying them out.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CRFs are still used for the tasks of image labeling and semantic image segmentation along with the DNNs. In fact, CRFs and DNNs are not self-excluding techniques and a lot of recent publications use both of them.

CRFs are based on probabilistic graphical models, where graph nodes and edges represent random variables, initialized with *potential functions*. DNN can be used as such potential function:

- [Conditional Random Fields Meet Deep Neural Networks for Semantic Segmentation](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~tvg/publications/2017/CRFMeetCNN4SemanticSegmentation.pdf)
- [Conditional Random Fields as Recurrent Neural Networks](https://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~szheng/papers/CRFasRNN.pdf)
- [Brain Tumor Segmentation with Deep Neural Network](http://www.professeurs.polymtl.ca/christopher.pal/miccai2014/brats2014_lisa_cnn_paper.pdf) (Future Work Section)

DCNN may be used for the feature extraction process, which is an essential step in applying CRFs:

- [Environmental Microorganism Classification Using Conditional Random Fields and Deep Convolutional Neural Networks](http://www.project-10.de/Kosov/files/PRJ_2018.pdf)
- [Conditional Random Field and Deep Feature Learning for Hyperspectral Image Segmentation](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.04483.pdf)

There are also toolkits, combining both CRFs and DNNs:

- [Direct graphical models C++ library](http://research.project-10.de/dgm/)